# Dolphin "Could not change permissions for" popup on copy for FreeNAS nfs4

Tags: permissions, kubuntu, filemanager, dolphin, nas

Every time I try to copy a file onto one of the network drives (M) dolphin comes up with following popup:

- "Could not change permissions for X"

For **each** file, possibly freezing my system if there are hundreds of them. Importantly the file still copies and with **correct** permissions, it's just super annoying to receive sometimes hundreds of these popups.

If I copy the same files to/from the same folders using **cp** or any other file manager such as Thunar, it works fine with no popups.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated. Prefer not change file managers since dolphin is by far the most stable I have used (apart from this issue).

Current fstab looks like this:

```
# Network drives
10.0.0.174:/mnt/Models/M                       /net/M          nfs4    _netdev,auto                             0       0
10.0.0.164:/data/O                             /net/O          nfs    _netdev,auto                              0       0
10.0.0.178:/mnt/P/P                            /net/P          nfs    _netdev,auto                              0       0
10.0.0.149:/data/X                             /net/X          nfs    _netdev,auto                              0       0
10.0.0.122:/data/                              /net/V          nfs    _netdev,auto                              0       0
10.0.0.174:/mnt/Models/M-snapshot-20190318     /net/M-Recover  nfs4    _netdev,auto                             0       0
```

All network drives run on FreeNAS, the problematic M is on 11.1 while the rest are on 11.2. I *could* upload config files but prefer not upload them publicly.

[popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Caie3.png)

Comment: I guess the underlying file system on the M drive is FAT or similar, which doesn't have the same support for permissions as the system you are copying from? Not a good solution, but a possible workaround might be to reformat M as ext4 or something like that. Of course, a Dolphin setting would be much better, but I am not aware of such an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug in Dolphin and issue got fixed in newer version